# Error occured after changing the apex Controller name

Tags: apex

Today  i have changed my apex Controller name in setup -> apex classes and that apex classes is refered in lightning component and i try to give the new apex class name its throwing error like

> Failed to save Pricebook_Group_and_Extension_Item.cmp: Invalid
>   definition for null:Pricebook_Grp_and_Extension_Item_Cntrl:
>   ApexService.getType() return null with currentNamespace: c, namespace:
>   null, name: Pricebook_Grp_and_Extension_Item_Cntrl: Source

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all the controller names in lightning components where i have refered the apex controller Name .Now the error is not occured again